# Conditional Statement in Excel for Very Specific Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, formula

Link to google doc: (edited out)
Me and my friend our tracking our wins and losses in a game. I'm interested in using excel to find some specific information but I don't know how to do it. So I want to find out how many games we won today.

I can figure out how many games I won using `=COUNTIF(B3:B999, "Win")`

And I can figure out how many games I played today using `=COUNTIF(E3:E999, TODAY())`

How can I combine these two to **figure out how many games I won today?**
Thanks for the help, I'm new to using excel formulas and have just been googling stuff so far. Even a link to teach me how to do it would be appreciated.

Thanks, the countifs worked

Comment: I thought you could use VBA in excel, yeah I have a countif but I need a two criterion to be met, not one so I don't think one countif will do the job

Comment: [Countifs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842?CorrelationId=55344501-fcd9-4a58-b62b-08d112b02f1e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) plural. Allows multiple criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS().

```
=COUNTIFS(B3:B999, "Win", E3:E999, TODAY())
```